# How to add temp files (images, txt, etc) to a temp directory and then access them in Python?

Tags: python

I want to create a temp directory names workdir and inside that I want to write some files and add some images and then read those files and images. But I do not understand how I can do this. I am new to the python just know the basics so if someone can help me I would appreciate it.

this is an example I picked up from stackoverflow as it was selected answer but it is not working for me.

```
import tempfile
import os

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as workdir:

    print('tmp dir name', workdir)

    # write file to tmp dir
    fout = open(os.path.join(workdir,'file.txt'), 'w')
    fout.write('test write')
    fout.close()

    print('file.txt location', workdir + 'lala.fasta')

    # working with the file is fine
    fin = open(workdir + 'file.txt', 'U')
    for line in fin:
        print(line)

    
    for file in os.listdir(workdir):
        print('searching in directory')
        print(file)
```

Comment: When you say "it is not working for me" can you provide more details? Is it throwing an exception, etc.?

Comment: This is the error I am getting

file.txt location /tmp/tmp4r1zdpqmlala.fasta
/home/aqsa/aqsa/practice.py:16: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
  fin = open(workdir + 'file.txt', 'U')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aqsa/aqsa/practice.py", line 16, in <module>
    fin = open(workdir + 'file.txt', 'U')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp4r1zdpqmfile.txt'

Comment: Is the indentation of your code the same as what you have posted? As it stands, you're exiting the context manager that "workdir" exists in, and I imagine the temporary directory is removed upon exit.

Comment: I have corrected the indentation it was wrong here only

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
# working with the file is fine
fin = open(workdir + 'file.txt', 'U')
```

`workdir` does not have a trailing `/`, so the path of the file it is trying to open is `/tmp/tmp4r1zdpqmfile.txt` (as noted in the error), instead of the expected `/tmp/tmp4r1zdpqm/file.txt`. Use `os.path.join()` (as is done earlier when writing to the file) to allow for platform agnostic combining of directories and files.

Additionally, the `'U'` file option is deprecated. Use something like `'w'`, `'r'`, or `'r+'` instead. See the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for more detail.